# Is there any docking layout that have content drag and drop functionality in js?

Tags: javascript, html

https://www.htmlelements.com/demos/docking-layout/visual-studio-style/
I have Used the above layout and created dynamic docking layouts
and html drag and drop Api to drag and drop the table  content inside  the docking layout below is the link to drag and drop Api
https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_draganddrop.asp
what I really want is use only one api that have both functionalities that is drag and drop of content and dragging of docking layout (functionality that's in the docking layout example link above).

```
<https://codepen.io/kaltura/pen/ExgdBYB>
```

> Due to APi conflict i am not able to use html drag and drop Api inside the docking layout Api.What i really want is to drag and drop content of table a to table b but inside  tag.
> above is link to code

> > I have used jQueryUi and jqxwidgets layouts.
> > Thanks in advance ..
> > regards,
> > Kaltura